# SimpleDateFormat parse is changing time according to timezone

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp

I get timestamps as a String in a stream and they are of the format `"2016-12-08 05:44:48 <timezone like IST, UTC>"` and `"2016-12-08 05:44:48 <timezone like +0000>"`

I want to convert the string to java.sql.Timestamp so I wrote a function as follows

```
private static Timestamp convertToTimestamp(String s) throws ParseException{
    String dateFormat = new String("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss z");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    Date d = sdf.parse(s);
    return new Timestamp(d.getTime());
}
```

When I run

```
Timestamp t = convertToTimestamp("2016-12-08 05:44:48 UTC");
System.out.println(t);
```

The output is `2016-12-08 11:14:48.0`

It is automatically converting into IST (Probably my JVM default). 
How to make the change so that the output time not changed to IST and is same as input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java's [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) do not store timezone.

They always track time in **UTC**.

When parsing a date string that includes a timezone, the string is correctly parsed and adjusted from the given timezone to UTC.

When parsing a date string without timezone, the string is parsed in the JVM's default timezoneand converted to UTC, unless another timezone has been explicitly given to the date parser (commonly [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)).

When *displaying* (aka formatting) a `Date`/`Timestamp`, it will be shown in the JVM's default timezone, unless otherwise specified.

The `Date`/`Timestamp` objects **cannot** store a timezone, so they cannot remember what the original timezone was.

If you need that, use Java 8's `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to ignore the time-zone when parsing the date

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```